# Displaying things in processing

Tags: java, function, scope, processing

I'm trying to write a program in processing to draw 100 ellipses with random x and y coordinates that don't overlap.

I wrote this code, but for some reason, nothing is displaying when I run it. It doesn't throw any errors or anything, but it just doesn't work.

```
static person[] population;

void setup()  {
  population=new person[100];
  size(1000,700);
  stroke(0);

  createPopulation(50);
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    fill(population[i].getR(), population[i].getG(), population[i].getB());
    ellipse(population[i].getX(), population[i].getY(), 50, 50);
  }

}

void draw()  {
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    fill(population[i].getR(), population[i].getG(), population[i].getB());
    ellipse(population[i].getX(), population[i].getY(), 50, 50);
  }
}


class person {
  int x,y;
  boolean immune;
  boolean sick;
  int r;
  int g;
  int b;

  person(int xPos, int yPos, boolean isImmune, boolean isSick){
    x=xPos;
    y=yPos;
    immune=isImmune;
    sick=isSick;
  }  

  void checkIfSick(){
    if(sick){
      r=255;
      g=0;
      b=0;
    }
    else{
      r=100;
      g=100;
      b=255;
    }
  }

  int getR(){
    return this.r;
  }
  int getG(){
    return this.g;
  }
  int getB(){
    return this.b;
  }
  int getX(){
    return this.x;
  }
  int getY(){
    return this.y;
  }
}

void createPopulation(int percentImmune){
  int[] xPositions=new int[100];
  int[] yPositions=new int[100];
  int i=0;
  while(i<percentImmune){
    boolean xMatch=false;
    boolean yMatch=false;
    int randX=(int)Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
    int randY=(int)Math.round(Math.random()*700);

    population[i]=new person(randX, randY, true, false);

    for(int n=0; n<i; n++){
      if(randX/25==xPositions[n]){
        xMatch=true;
      }
      if(randY/25==yPositions[n]){
        yMatch=true;
      }
    }

    if(xMatch==false || yMatch==false){
      xPositions[i]=randX/25;
      yPositions[i]=randY/25;
      i++;
    }
  }
  while(i<100){
    boolean xMatch=false;
    boolean yMatch=false;
    int randX=(int)Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
    int randY=(int)Math.round(Math.random()*700);

    population[i]=new person(randX, randY, false, false);

    for(int n=0; n<i; n++){
      if(randX/25==xPositions[n]){
        xMatch=true;
      }
      if(randY/25==yPositions[n]){
        yMatch=true;
      }
    }

    if(xMatch==false || yMatch==false){
      xPositions[i]=randX/25;
      yPositions[i]=randY/25;
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, SO doesn't provide and debugging service.

Comment: @WasiAhmad I'm sorry if it comes off like I'm asking you to debug my code, but this is my first time using processing so I'm just hoping for someone to let me know what I did wrong here. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the scope of the variables, but I'm still fairly new to this stuff so I'd appreciate if you could let me know if that's the case.

Comment: how is this code being called?

Comment: @ScaryWombat As I understand it, in processing it just runs the setup once then loops draw forever. You don't have to explicitly call either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get into the habit of debugging your program. Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on debugging Processing sketches [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging).

My guess is that your code is getting stuck in one of your `while` loops inside your `createPopulation()` function. Debugging will tell you which one, and then you can fix your error.

You should also get into the habit of [breaking your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program). You shouldn't write your entire program and then wonder why it's not working. Instead, work in small chunks that only test one thing at a time. Then when you encounter a bug, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your entire sketch.

Comment: Yes, in `createPopulation` the value of `i` is not being incremented in every situation potentially causing an endless loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat Right. But the real lesson here is that OP needs to learn how to debug their program.

Comment: OP, also see [talk to the duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: Thanks so much! I read your tutorial and I'll be doing that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

use "random()" to display persons at random locations